# How to overcome blank login screen using 2 monitors with laptop (Intel i965)

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, multiple-monitors, i915

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (Kernel: Linux 4.10.0-40-generic (x86_64), Desktop: LXDE(Lubuntu)) on a Dell Latitude D630 (Intel GM965 graphics). It works fine with just the (undocked) laptop, but If I try to boot with 2 external monitors (VGA + DVI) attached (laptop lid open or closed), I get blank screen at login. Once logged in, this can be fixed by explicitly turning off the laptop screen ("LVDS-1") in xrandr-autostart.desktop by executing:

```
xrandr --output DVI-D-1 --mode 1920x1200 --rate 59.95 --pos 1280x0 --rotate normal
--output VGA-1 --mode 1280x1024 --rate 60.02 --pos 0x128 --rotate normal
--output LVDS-1 --off
--output VIRTUAL1 --off'
```

Looking at the output of dmesg, this seems to be a (not uncommon) firmware problem (though I see no mention of a fix in later firmware release notes for my machine):

```
[Firmware Bug]: Duplicate ACPI video bus devices for the same VGA
  controller, please try module parameter "video.allow_duplicates=1"if the
  current driver doesn't work.
```

To no avail, I have tried adding the following to /etc/default/grub:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="video.allow_duplicates=1 quiet splash"
```

Although this (or various things I have tried) do get me seeing a "Lubuntu" graphic logo followed by a screen of terminal-style messages (on bothexternal  monitors), the final of which is saying "Plymouth boot screen", it just stays on that screen without displaying login (even though it lets me blindly log in).

Checking for the VGA kernel modules the ACPI warning would relate to...

```
lspci -nnk | grep -A3 VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) [8086:2a02] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Dell Latitude D630 [1028:01f9]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915, intelfb
```

It seems that various i915 bugs were fixed in the earlier 4.6 linux kernel, but I haven't got far with the various suggestions on this forum or elsewhere. I tried setting options for one or both related video modules in control file /etc/modprobe.d/fix-video.conf:

```
options i915 video.allow_duplicates=1
options intelfb video.allow_duplicates=1
```

but this didn't fix the problem, if anything making the system less stable. It did add 2 extra lines in the terminal-style screen after the (plymouth bootscreen message) relating to backlight control, but I don't think that is the issue.

My current setting is no extra modprobe.d files, but with the following in grub (which gives me Lubuntu logo, followed by terminal-style screen):

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i915.modeset=1 quiet splash"
```

Even if I can't overcome the firmware bug, if there was a way to set things up to turn off the laptop screen for the login screen (as in the arandr script above) that would be great - particularly as with the arandr script if the laptop is running standalone, it just gets ignored (the laptop screen comes on).

Other info about the video that may be helpful, ascertained from within my desktop, with the 2 external monitors having turned off laptop monitor with arandr:

```
sudo lshw -c video
  *-display:0             
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 0c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:27 memory:f6e00000-f6efffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:efe8(size=8) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display:1 UNCLAIMED
       description: Display controller
       product: Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (secondary)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2.1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
       version: 0c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f6f00000-f6ffffff
```

Comment: many system will only support 2 monitors even though they have ports for 2 externals.

Comment: @ravery that's not a worry for me if I could at least get it to show some sort of login screen on one of the external monitors!

Comment: Are you using LightDM and Lightdm Greeter? LightDM allows for a display script. Thus you could make a script to detect monitors and issue the appropriate xrandr command.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution isn't ideal as it doesn't fix the driver bug, but it does make the login screen visible on the laptop and (one) of the external monitors (after a period of blank when it should have been showing the Lubuntu logo)...

As pointed out by @ravery (thanks!) as my system is set up to use the Lightdm greeter, I can modify the greeter script to enable/disable displays using arandr:

Add a new config file (using sudo) to override the default greeter script using your editor of choice:

```
sudo gvim /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-myconfig.conf
```

and enter the following:

```
# Redirect greeter script to my version
[Seat:*]
greeter-wrapper=/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/my-lightdm-greeter-session
```

Copy across the existing greeter script and edit it:

```
sudo cp -p /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-greeter-session /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/my-lightdm-greeter-session
sudo gvim /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/my-lightdm-greeter-session
```

to add the following line to turn on laptop screen ("LVDS-1") and VGA, but turn off the DVI-D:

```
xrandr --output LVDS-1 --auto --output VGA-1 --auto --same-as LVDS-1 --output DVI-D-1 --off
```

Although this only switches on one of the 2 possible external monitors, within Lubuntu the user session can be configured to switch to the desired 
monitor setup using the "Monitor Settings" menu item to configure the setup file: ~/.config/autostart/lxrandr-autostart.desktop
(Helpfully even though I have set this file to turn off the laptop screen, when the laptop is used undocked it sensibly ignores this advice and displays on the laptop screen... though this wasn't the case if lxrandr was similarly invoked for the greeter in the my-lightdm-greeter-session script).